# Processing of multipart/form-data request failed

Tags: file, file-upload, upload

File upload mechanism is added to my existing application which is deployed to WebSphere 7. I use commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar for the file upload. During testing, I encountered below exception:

```
 [5/2/13 18:00:00:773 CST] 0000001b SystemOut     O 18:00:00,773  INFO AccountsController:156 - Session is valid.
 [5/2/13 18:04:42:299 CST] 0000001e servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet dispatcher in application SunLinkOnline_ST. Exception created : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Async operation timed out
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
at ph.com.sunlife.sunlink.filter.MFSanitizerFilter.doFilter(MFSanitizerFilter.java:38)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:445)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:504)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:275)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Async operation timed out
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:172)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Async operation timed out
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:371)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:165)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Async operation timed out
```

Could someone please share some insights what is causing above exception. Though the exception may point to server long response or due to handling of timeout in server but is there a way to resolve this? Like handling of exception in code side? Your help is much appreciated. Please let me know if I need to include other information to resolve this exceptions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like file upload time out need to be increased. I came across same situation once but what i needed was to upload my application to websphere via admin console. Since my application is a large one i have to increase time out for admin console.

Since your scenario is for file upload in application hosted in websphere you have to change the time out of different queue.

Please find following URLs

[IBM Websphere timeout custom properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/xrun_transport.html)

[IBM changing time out in HTTP queues](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rrun_chain_httpcustom.html)

[what i did in my scenario](http://sahanlm.tumblr.com/post/54505834519/websphere-increasing-wait-time-when-uploading-an)